# batch multiple variable to one / double quotes

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hi guys im trying to add multiple variables to one.

```
ET CA1="C:/Users/"
SET CA2=Bla
SET CA3="/New Folder/"
SET CA=%CA1%%CA2:~%%CA3%"
echo %CA%
```

This is the Output

```
"C:/Users/"Bla"/New Folder/"
```

When i do this i always get double quotes `"` in the middle no matter what i do.
I have tried to use :~1,-1%" to remove the last char but the output is just "l" in the middle.

The "end product" i want to archive is to ask the username by prompt and use the string for something else. This was the best ( and surely not best) i could think of. to add 3 different Variable to get the right path.

Is there maybe another way to just have something like this:

```
set /p Username="Insert Username"  -> pete for example
set CA="C:/Users/%CA%/New Folder/" 
echo %CA%
```

Output:

```
"C:/Users/pete/New Folder/"
```

Comment: It seems to work best when quotes are -not- part of the value in a `SET` statement. Set the value without quotes, then use quotes whenever the variable is used. `SET "V=C:\Users"`, then use it as `DIR "%V%"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your first example try this:

```
@echo off
SET "CA1=C:/Users/"
SET "CA2=Bla"
SET "CA3=/New Folder/"
SET "CA=%CA1%%CA2:~%%CA3%"
echo "%CA%"
pause
```

which simply echo's:

```
"C:/Users/Bla/New Folder/"
```

Note that you move the quotes to before the variable name, and not after the `=`

On the second part, where you require user input. there are 2 methods:

**User input method**

```
set /p "myuser=Insert Username: "
set "CA=C:/Users/%myuser%/New Folder/" 
echo "%CA%"
pause
```

**or Get the name from environment.**

```
@echo off
set "CA=C:/Users/%username%/New Folder/" 
echo "%CA%"
pause
```

Note, the second method gets the `%username%` variable of the user currently logged in from the environment and will set it automatically.

Finally, some hints. always use `help` from `cmd.exe` to find relevant commands
Use each command with the `/?`switch to get more information on it's abilities. i.e `set /?`

Also, NEVER modify existing environment variables. For instance in your example `set /p Username="Insert Username..` `%username% is already an existing environment variable, rather create something unique like`mysername`

To test this, simple do from `cmd.exe` `echo %username%` and to understand where it got it from, simply run `set` to display Environment variables.

Comment: Ok that did the trick thanks :) I just started with batch im kinda missing the basics and it is hard to just find such a basic info when u dont know u are doing it wrong :)

Big thanks !

Comment: @batchn00b Just follow the help i suggested at the bottom of the answer and you will get alot of info